# How can I fix the 'Missing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Response Header' webfont issue?

Tags: .htaccess, fonts, cors, font-face, webfonts

For some reason fonts have stopped rendering on my sites. The fonts are stored locally, on the same server as the site.

I looked up the problem and it seems to be a `Missing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Response Header` but I cannot understand the solution for this.

All the various sites say to do is to use: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

But as I'm primarily front end I do not know where to put it. Is this something my host can help with?

What can I do to fix the issue?

EDIT:

the site in question is: http://cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au/

The phone number, for example, at the top right should be Bebas font but it is defaulting to Impact.

In the console, I get the errors:

> Font from origin 'http://www.cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://www.cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au' is therefore not allowed access.

I contact my host who said to put:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au"
```

in my .htaccess file but this has no change.

Comment: I think your solution is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Comment: @Croises thanks but unfortunately that makes no sense to me

Comment: [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15024333/440546)

Comment: Is it a shared host or a dedicated server?

Comment: Where are you hosting your site from?  Apache?  Shared hosting?  C-Panel?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your HTML you have set a "base" tag:

```
<base href="http://www.cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au/">
```

1. Delete that line from your HTML if you don't need it. This should make the fonts work when viewed from http://cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au.
2. You'll probably need to redirect http://www.cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au to http://cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au

Comment: I am not using <base tag, even though it gives error

Answer (score 29):

If you are just interested in the use of  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

You can do that with this `.htaccess` file at the site root.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Some useful information here:
http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Did you try this .htaccess ?

Comment: Don't just set it to "*". That can be dangerous.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume your host is using C-Panel - and that it's probably HostGator or GoDaddy.  In both cases they use C-Panel (in fact, a lot of hosts do) to make the Server administration as easy as possible on you, the end user.  Even if you are hosting through someone else - see if you can log in to some kind of admin panel and find an **.htaccess** file that you can edit.  (Note: The period before just means that it's a "hidden" file/directory).

Once you find the htaccess file add the following line:

1. `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` Just to see if it works.
   **Warning: Do not use this line on a production server**

It should work.  If not, call your host and ask them why the line isn't working - they'll probably be able to help you quickly from there.

2. Once you do have the above working change the `*` to the address of the requesting domain `http://cyclistinsuranceaustralia.com.au/`.  You may find an issue with canonical addressing (including the www) and if so you may need to configure your host for a redirect.  That's a different and smaller bridge to cross though.  You'll at least be in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case the issue seem to be with accessing the site from non-canonical url (www.site.com vs. site.com).

Instead of fixing CORS issue (which may require writing proxy to server fonts with proper CORS headers depending on service provider) you can normalize your Urls to always server content on canonical Url and simply redirect if one requests page without "www.".

Alternatively you can upload fonts to different server/CDN that is known to have CORS headers configured or you can easily do so.

Answer (score 0):

we had similar header issue with Amazon (AWS) S3 presigned Post failing on some browsers.

point was to tell bucket CORS to expose header `<ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>`

more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37465080/473040

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact problem with fontawesome-webfont.woff2 throwing a 406 error on a shared host (Cpanel). I was working on the elusive "cookie-less domain" for a Wordpress Multisite project and my "www.domain.tld" pages would have the following error (3 times) in Chrome:

> Font from origin 'http://static.domain.tld' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.tld' is therefore not allowed access.

and in Firefox, a little more detail:

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://static.domain.tld/wp-content/themes/some-theme-here/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
>   font-awesome.min.css:4:14
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://static.domain.tld/wp-content/themes/some-theme-here/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I got to QWANT-ing around (QWANT.com = fantastic) and found this SO post:

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard subdomains, ports and protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003332/access-control-allow-origin-wildcard-subdomains-ports-and-protocols)

An hour in chat with different Shared Host support staff (one didn't even know about F12 in a browser...) then waiting for a response to the ticket that got cut after no joy while playing with mod_security. I tried to cobble the code for the .htaccess file together from the post in the meantime, and got this to work to remedy the 406 errors, flawlessly:

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?domain\.tld(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{CORS}e" env=CORS
        Header merge  Vary "Origin"
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

I added that to the top of my .htaccess at the site root and now I have a new Uncle named Bob. (***of course change the domain.tld parts to whatever your domain that you are working with is...)

My FAVORITE part of this post though is the ability to RegEx OR (|) multiple sites into this CORS "hack" by doing:

> To allow Multiple sites:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(.+\.)?(othersite\.com|mywebsite\.com)(:\d{1,5})?$" CORS=$0
```

This fix honestly kind of blew my mind because I've ran into this issue before, working with Dev's at Fortune 500 companies that are MILES above my knowledgebase of Apache and couldn't solve problems like this without getting IT to tweak on Apache settings.

This is kind of the magic bullet to fix all those CDN issues with cookie-less (or near cookie-less if you use CloudFlare...) domains to reduce the amount of unnecessary web traffic from cookies that get sent with every image request only to be ditched like a bad blind date by the server.

Super Secure, Super Elegant. Love it: You don't have to open up your servers bandwidth to resource thieves / hot-link-er types.

Props to a collective effort from these 3 brilliant minds for solving what was once thought to unsolvable with .htaccess, whom I pieced this code together from:

@Noyo
https://stackoverflow.com/users/357774/noyo

@DaveRandom
https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom

@pratap-koritala
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4401569/pratap-koritala