# Getting Foundation Icons to display in Rails 4 / Cloudfront Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront, foundation-icon-fonts

I have managed to deploy my Rails 4 app to Heroku. All assets are served from a Cloudfront instance. This part works perfectly.

The only issue I'm experiencing, is the fact that my foundation icons are not being served. This is as a result of a CORS issue as seen [here](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/cors-ie-cloudfront/) and [here](http://unsharptech.com/2014/08/28/cloudfront-cors-with-custom-origin/). I have read that AWS have implemented a solution for the CORS issue quite recently and that this shouldn't be a problem anymore, but I can't seem to fix/understand my issue.

I have tried the solutions above. I have also tried to make use of the ["font_assets gem"](https://github.com/ericallam/font_assets), as seen in another post, but I'm still presented with the following error:

```
".../assets/foundation-icons-8c44c3feedae5331a281278ea3ba91d2255928a2f3010d316d6fbb9052e0c2ec.woff. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."
```

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009425/how-can-i-fix-the-missing-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-response-header