# how to send json request in ajax post method

Tags: ajax, json

I'm trying to post json request in ajax call, but I'm not receiving any success response from the request.

Please find my below code: what I'm doing wrong here:

It hit the url and i'm getting 200 ok status but it always go error condition..

Can someone help, what i need to change to work:

I tried data: JSON.stringify({key:"value",key1: "value1"}) - but this also didn't help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function JSONTest() {

 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/test/toSend',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{key:"value",key1: "value1"}',
    processData: false,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){

        alert("success..." +data);
        $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});   

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please provide an output of data and/or errorThrown.

Comment: I'm getting this error -Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  http://localhost:8080/test/toSend -Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). <unknown>

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is not hooked up as a promise! Use the below code!

```
function JSONTest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/test/toSend',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{key:"value",key1: "value1"}',
        processData: false
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error errorThrown");
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! I used the above code, http request is not going and directly coming to error, I'm not seeing any error in console.

Comment: Are you executing the JSONTest? What is the error you are receiving? Just the .error?

Comment: Sorry, updated! `.error` is deprecated and replaced with `.fail`.

Comment: If i remove contentType: 'application/json' - request goes and showing 200 ok status in firebug xhr but again its doing to error block only

Comment: Try the update, should correct the issue. I did not remove the contentType but will once you confirm.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting any error - it simply goes to .error block... I tried removing content type: and data: - still its going to .error block

Comment: I updated the example above. Please see `.error` is now `.fail`. That was a mistake on my part not taking into account `.error` being deprecated.

Comment: Got it.. :) I'm getting this error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/test/toSend. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: This is a separate issue not to do with the code but rather your server or the server you are referencing. If you are making a call from a localhost, AJAX does not work from localhost. You will need to upload to a server and test calling a free open API or your localhost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009425/how-can-i-fix-the-missing-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-response-header There are some nice references and information on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use `JSON.stringify({key:"value",key1: "value1"})` you need to load this script :

[JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)