# Fonts (fontawesome) icons not working in opencart 2.1.0.2 But working after click on other page

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, opencart2.x

I am getting this error after doing inspect element in browser.

Font awesome icons not showing properly on website showing instead of square

Font from origin 'http://www.example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

One thing I observe that when I load my website by simply enter url, that time not loading font awesome icons but works after navigating on other page

Answer (score 0):

Its **www.site.com** vs. **site.com**

Solutions  -

1. You can solve by redirecting http://www.example.com to
   http://example.com
2. You can do that with this `.htaccess` file at the site root.

   ```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   ```

Please check - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009425](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009425/how-can-i-fix-the-missing-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-response-header)